# How to trigger Quarkus OIDC-Client trigger on Header Authorization: Basic

Tags: authorization, keycloak, quarkus, bearer-token

I'm working to convert a Spring application to Quarkus.  I want both Bearer and Basic Authentication to work.  This will also use Keycloak Authorization Service (main reason I'm moving to Quarkus).

The quarkus.oidc configuration works great and I have no problem with the Bearer Token Authorization.

The quarkus.oidc-client configuration does contain grant-type password option that I assume I could use to convert a Authorization: Basic Header to username/password and generate a Bearer Token.  This is the spot I think I'm stuck.

Do I need to extend HttpAuthenticationMechanism? The extended class would invoke the oidc-client with the client credentials, grant-type=password and username/password from the Authorization: Basic header?

application.properties

```
quarkus.http.auth
quarkus.http.auth.basic=true
quarkus.http.auth.permission.basic-bearer.paths=/api/config/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.basic-bearer.policy=authenticated
#end quarkus.http.auth

#quarkus.oidc
quarkus.oidc.enabled=true
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${keycloakAuthServerUrl}/realms/${keycloakRealm}
quarkus.oidc.discovery-enabled=true
quarkus.oidc.client-id=${keycloakResource}
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=${keycloakCredentialsSecret}
#end quarkus.oidc

#quarkus.oidc-client
quarkus.oidc-client.enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client.auth-server-url=${keycloakAuthServerUrl}/realms/${keycloakRealm}
quarkus.oidc-client.discovery-enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client.client-id=${keycloakResource}
quarkus.oidc-client.credentials.secret=${keycloakCredentialsSecret}
quarkus.oidc-client.grant.type=password
```

Do I need to add SecurityIdentity below?

```
@Path("/api/config")
public class ConfigController {
    @Inject
    Tokens tokens;

    String success;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendOk() throws JsonProcessingException {
        success = tokens.getAccessToken();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return Response.ok(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this)).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/owners")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendOwners() throws JsonProcessingException {
        success = tokens.getAccessToken();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return Response.ok(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this)).build();
    }
}
```

I was trying to get the quarkus.oidc-client to manage Basic Authorization header without need to add my own HttpAuthenticationMechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did need to implement a custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism.  Code and config below.

```
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@ApplicationScoped
public class DexAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

    @Inject
    private OidcAuthenticationMechanism oidc;

    @Inject
    private OidcClients oidcClients;


    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> authenticate(RoutingContext context, IdentityProviderManager identityProviderManager) {
        String authHeader = context.request().headers().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        String[] authSplit = authHeader.split("\\s+");
        if (authSplit.length == 2) {
            if ("BEARER".equalsIgnoreCase(authSplit[0])) {
                return oidc.authenticate(context, identityProviderManager);
            } else if ("BASIC".equalsIgnoreCase(authSplit[0])) {
                OidcClient basic = oidcClients.getClient("basic");
                Map<String, String> grantParams = new HashMap<>();
                final String[] values = new String(
                        Base64.getDecoder().decode(authSplit[1])
                        , StandardCharsets.UTF_8
                ).split(":");
                if (values.length == 2) {
                    grantParams.put("username", values[0]);
                    grantParams.put("password", values[1]);
                    Uni<Tokens> tokensUni = basic.getTokens(grantParams);
                    tokensUni.onItem().transform(
                            item -> item.getAccessToken()
                    ).onFailure().invoke(
                            Throwable::printStackTrace
                    ).runSubscriptionOn(
                            Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor()
                    ).subscribe().with(item -> subscribeToTokens(context, item));
                    return tokensUni.chain(i -> subscribeToTokens(context, i.getAccessToken()))
                            .chain(i -> oidc.authenticate(i, identityProviderManager));
                }
            } else if ("API".equalsIgnoreCase(authSplit[0])) {
                OidcClient api = oidcClients.getClient("api");
                Uni<Tokens> tokensUni = api.refreshTokens(authSplit[1]);
                tokensUni.onItem().transform(
                        item -> item.getAccessToken()
                ).onFailure().invoke(
                        Throwable::printStackTrace
                ).runSubscriptionOn(
                        Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor()
                ).subscribe().with(item -> subscribeToTokens(context, item));
                return tokensUni.chain(i -> subscribeToTokens(context, i.getAccessToken()))
                        .chain(i -> oidc.authenticate(i, identityProviderManager));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cheese and crackers");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Double cheese and crackers");
        }
        return Uni.createFrom().failure(new AuthenticationFailedException());
    }

    private Uni<RoutingContext> subscribeToTokens(RoutingContext context, String accessToken) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(updateRoutingContext(context, accessToken));
    }

    private RoutingContext updateRoutingContext(RoutingContext context, String accessToken) {
        context.request().headers().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken);
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<ChallengeData> getChallenge(RoutingContext context) {
        return oidc.getChallenge(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<? extends AuthenticationRequest>> getCredentialTypes() {
        return oidc.getCredentialTypes();
    }
}
```

And add multiple OIDC clients to chain in the different authentication approaches.

```
#quarkus.oidc-client.default
quarkus.oidc-client.enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client.auth-server-url=${keycloakAuthServerUrl}/realms/${keycloakRealm}
quarkus.oidc-client.discovery-enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client.client-id=${keycloakResource}
quarkus.oidc-client.credentials.secret=${keycloakCredentialsSecret}
quarkus.oidc-client.grant.type=client
#end quarkus.oidc-client.default

#quarkus.oidc-client.basic
quarkus.oidc-client."basic".enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client."basic".auth-server-url=${keycloakAuthServerUrl}/realms/${keycloakRealm}
quarkus.oidc-client."basic".discovery-enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client."basic".client-id=${keycloakResource}
quarkus.oidc-client."basic".credentials.secret=${keycloakCredentialsSecret}
quarkus.oidc-client."basic".grant.type=password
#end quarkus.oidc-client.basic

#quarkus.oidc-client.api
quarkus.oidc-client."api".enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client."api".auth-server-url=${keycloakAuthServerUrl}/realms/${keycloakRealm}
quarkus.oidc-client."api".discovery-enabled=true
quarkus.oidc-client."api".client-id=${keycloakResource}
quarkus.oidc-client."api".credentials.secret=${keycloakCredentialsSecret}
quarkus.oidc-client."api".grant.type=refresh
#end quarkus.oidc-client.api
```